# Is it possible to load page bulider Visual composer editor default in Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, visual-composer

Am install Visual composer plugin it's working fine,Am custom to Visual composer editor to pages and posts,Once Click Pages -> Add New it's not loaded visual composer editor default.Once Click Backend Editor Button then only it changes visual composer editor.Is there any plugin or any changes to loaded to Visual composer editor default in Wordpress.

**I need to Load Visual composer editor Default when Click Pages -> Add New pages loaded.**

Answer (score 1):

I would trigger the VC button "BACKEND EDITOR" after tinymce initialization. In tinymce 4 using jQuery you could trigger the click event after the initialization in this way:

```
tinymce.init({}).then(function(editors) {
   jQuery('.composer-switch:not(.vc_backend-status) .wpb_switch-to-composer').trigger('click');
});
```

where wpb_switch-to-composer is the class of the VC button and .composer-switch:not(.vc_backend-status) is selector of the button wrapper when the editor is not VC